# What type of vector field has an zero integral of divergence over all 3D space?

Tags: integration, vector-fields, divergence-operator

Assume $\mathbf{V}(\mathbf{x})$ is a vector field in 3D space. Its divergence is $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{V}(\mathbf{x})$. The integration of this divergence over all 3D space is $I=\displaystyle{\int\nabla\cdot \mathbf{V}(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}}$. My question is: under what condition can $I$ always be zero? The more general the condition is, the better the answer would be. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

One classic condition is that $V$ vanishes at infinity, in which case the integral of divergence is zero by Stokes's Theorem.

Comment: Where is divergence in Stokes's Theorem?

Comment: @user5280911 I'm not sure what you're asking... just plug in a vector field? $$\int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot v \,dA = \int_{\partial \Omega} v\cdot \hat{n}\,ds?$$

Comment: This equation looks like a Divergence Theorem, not Stokes' Theorem. In Divergence Theorem, the left is an integral over a 3D volume while the right is an integral over a closed surface of the aforementioned volume.

Comment: @user5280911 Sure. The Divergence Theorem, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, Green's Theorem, etc etc etc are all special cases of Stokes's Theorem. See e.g. Wikipedia for the full details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem

Comment: @user7530 would it be true also with perioic boundary conditions over V? if so, why?

Comment: @FrancescoBoccardo Sure---periodic boundary conditions is equivalent to gluing the boundary to itself, so that you end up with a manifold without boundary. In that case the integral on the right is trivially zero. (This is assuming the result of the gluing is orientable---I'm not 100% what happens when it's not.)